# Laravel | Restrict login based on user role

Tags: laravel, authentication, eloquent, middleware

So in our Laravel application there are 2 roles (internet clients and admins). Below is the DB schema

```
users(id, username, password)
roles(id, name)
role_user (user_id, role_id)
```

We want to allow **[www.site.com/login](http://www.site.com/login)** route to log only users with role 'Client'.

Note that we don't want to check for the role once the user is logged and force logout.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay quick solution we found is to override **login** function in **LoginController** to check if username has an admin role then fail the login

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $unAuthorizedRoles = ['ADMIN'];
        $exist = User::where('username', $request->username)->whereHas('roles', static function ($query) use ($unAuthorizedRoles) {
            return $query->whereIn('name', $unAuthorizedRoles);
        })->exists();

        if ($exist)
            return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);

        [...]

    }
```